# Error terminal node.js (El término '$' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable.)

Tags: nodejs, terminal, variables-globales

En mi anterior pregunta se me ofreció un enlace para iniciarme en node.js

[guia](https://lenguajejs.com/npm/administracion/crear-nuevo-proyecto/)

He comenzado paso a paso y en seguida me ha aparecido este fallo:

```
(El término '$' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable.)
```

Llevo una hora cambiando entornos e variables (siguiendo a google) , actualizando node y npm, instalando paquetes como typescript... y el error sigue en el terminal de VCS o PowerShell.

¿Qué paso me estoy saltando?¿Por qué los terminales no reconocen estos comandos?
¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Como apunte, me gustaría saber porqué con el simbolo $ me da error y sin el, se ejecuta el comando. (me pasa con npm, node...)

Sin embargo, no consigo crear carpetas dentro de carpetas:

```
mkdir -p src/{assets,js,css} ---> no funciona, pero sin las llaves, crea carpetas
```

Y mucho menos archivos:

```
touch src/index.html
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto? Itero que ya he añadido las variables de entorno, y tras reiniciar, el problema continua.

Gracias!

Comment: El símbolo `$` no es un comando para ejecutarse. Es parte de algunas consolas en donde indica que puedes escribir un comando. En resumen, no debes colocar el símbolo `$`

Comment: Debes tener en cuenta el entorno donde pones los comandos... por ejemplo `touch` es un comando de entornos unix, no te va a funcionar si lo pones en un entorno `windows` por ejemplo. Mas que "copiar y pegar" comandos a ciegas, debes tambien mirar que intenta hacer ese comando y revisar de que manera lo haces en tu entorno de trabajo.

Comment: Ya, ya, gracias a ambos. Evidentemente, lo acabé descubriendo rápido. Las prisas del novato. Por suerte, he podido dedicar bastantes horas y estoy avanzando con esto.